# Firebase: Why call `signOut()` after signing in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'AIza…',
  authDomain: '<PROJECT_ID>.firebasepp.com'
});

// As httpOnly cookies are to be used, do not persist any state client side.
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);

// When the user signs in with email and password.
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('user@example.com', 'password').then(user => {
  // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
  return user.getIdToken().then(idToken = > {
    // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
    // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
    // ...
    const csrfToken = getCookie('csrfToken')
    return postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/sessionLogin', idToken, csrfToken);
  });
}).then(() => {
  // A page redirect would suffice as the persistence is set to NONE.
  return firebase.auth().signOut();
}).then(() => {
  window.location.assign('/profile');
});
```

Upon signing in with Firebase, why call `return firebase.auth().signOut();`?

Isn't the point to sign in?

On Firebase docs, it states:
`On success, the state should be cleared from the client side storage.`

What is the point of this?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I'd never seen this, and it's definitely not very obvious.

Normally Firebase Authentication store the authentication state in **local storage**. That's where then reads it back from when for example you reload the page.

---

When you use a session cookie, the authentication state is stored in a **cookie** on the client. You can see this happening in the server-side code shown in the documentation on [managing cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) (where the code in your question also comes from). For Node.js for example it shows:

> ```
> ...
> res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
> ...
> ```

---

So now we have two places where the authentication state is stored:

1. In local storage by the SDK.
2. In a cookie, by the custom service code.

Calling `firebase.auth().signOut()` removes the authentication state from local storage, only leaving the one in the cookie.

---

As the comments in the code already say:

> ```
> // As httpOnly cookies are to be used, do not persist any state client side.
> firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
>
> ...
>
> // A page redirect would suffice as the persistence is set to NONE.
> return firebase.auth().signOut();
> ```

That first statement ensures the SDK will no longer persist the authentication state. But there might be a stale state still stored, so it's best to clear it by signing out.

Comment: So I guess the author is assuming you **used** to use JWT auth, and need to clear it?

Comment: That's one scenario I could think of. There might be more.

Comment: Yea, I think that might be it then.